# How to display a student's record (only who logged in) in java connected with database?

Tags: java

i write this code to connect java with database, and i have a login pahe where i entered username and that should display the record of the student who logged in for that i have executed this query

```
 String query= "select * from Student where Name = '" + new Login().equals(jTextField1.getText()) + "'";
```

but it's not working .

Comment: new Login() looks so wrong.

Comment: **Warning:** your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use prepared statements instead. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Your query compares name with new Login().equals(jTextField1.getText()) i.e. which runs equals method which would either return true or false.

Also you are trying to compare login object with String which compiler wont be happy with.

You should change your line from:

```
String query ="select * from Student where Name = '" +new Login().equals(jTextField1.getText()) +"'" ;
```

To:

```
String query ="select * from Student where Name = '" + jTextField1.getText() +"'" ;
```

Note - Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection, better use [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and provide input like username say via map.